# Web security of arbitrary JS/HTML uploads

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, templating

I'm not sure how to phrase the question so please feel free to recommend edits for the title, but I have a couple of general (but hopefully specific enough) security questions about a few web development practices I've encountered.

There are templating systems like EJS that allow code to be run on the client-side. If a web app allows users to upload JS and HTML files to the server to be served to the public, what are some (if any) of the security concerns? Note that uploaded JS/HTML files will only be served publicly by being placed in an appropriate folder, i.e. an assets folder.

If a templating system is not allowed but the user is still allowed to upload any arbitrary JS/HTML file, what security concerns remain?

Some assumptions:

- a Node.js server with some MVC framework
- Sensitive datasets are stored on the server but can only be accessed directly by the Node.js server
- A user can only access a dataset by requesting for it, and an admin can approve/reject the request
- Not worried about social engineering attacks such as phishing (looking more for attacks that compromise the data)

If this is too general, let me know how I can clarify. I'm only looking for a push in the right direction.

Comment: In case your user's are allowed to upload arbitrary JS and HTML code they could use this for CSRF, which could compromise other people's data, right?

Comment: True, but I'm mostly looking for compromise on the data held on the server.

Comment: You may want to ask this kind of question on another SE site, like [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/). Do read their equivalent of the How to Ask page to make sure it is relevant to that site. As it is, this question seems overly broad.

Comment: I did consider it, but I couldn't formulate my question in a more specific manner, since it is really open-ended for me. If some clarifications from answers here are made, then I'll definitely move over to Security SE if I have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really just looking to protect the data and integrity of your server:
Just escape the files, so that these are only treated as strings and can't be executed. Later you use the string and just write it plain back into a file.

Make sure that the server, which serves the files later (e.g. from the assets folder) has really limited rights (just what you need to serve these). I would recommend that you split your node.js server into two. One which is serving the files (very limited functionality) and the other which escapes the uploaded files and puts them to e.g. your assets folder.

However be aware that other's could use your service for CSRF and some other malicious stuff.